# Не получаю данные из Returing ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

Записываю данные в одну таблицу,хочу записать присвоееный id, в другую 
   таблицу.

```
With userid AS(
INSERT INTO public."user"(nickname) VALUES('Daheim') RETURNING id
)

INSERT INTO public.chat("nameChat", user_id) VALUES ('Sex',userid);
```

> ```
> ОШИБКА:  столбец "userid" не существует
> LINE 5: ...INTO public.chat("nameChat", user_id) VALUES ('Sex',userid);
>                                                                ^
> HINT:  Возможно, предполагалась ссылка на столбец "chat.user_id".
> ```
>
> ********** Ошибка **********
>
> ОШИБКА: столбец "userid" не существует
>   SQL-состояние: 42703
>   Подсказка: Возможно, предполагалась ссылка на столбец "chat.user_id".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`userid` в данном случае — это [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html), т.е. о нём следует думать как о «таблице», поэтому с `WITH` запрос должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
WITH userid AS(
  INSERT INTO public."user"(nickname) VALUES('Daheim') RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO public.chat("nameChat", user_id) SELECT 'Sex', id FROM userid;
```